# AngularDart Cardview Component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-dart

I'm new to AngularDart and start bootstraping my first app with it. I'm struggling in AngularDart since its components isn't complete and not similar to [material.angular.io](http://material.angular.io). I also can't find cardview container on [AngularDart Component Examples](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/).
If it's not available yet, how to create cardview component from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Response from similar discussion: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/211

Performance is a main focus of the these components. We generally avoid creating a full component with the overhead of change detection for something that can be achieved with css styling alone.

I'd suggest using the styling offered here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-card

Comment: We can see this example in [AngularDart Gallery documentation](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_card).